# error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xxxxxxxxx.git'

Tags: django, git, heroku

I got an error,error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xxxxxxxxx.git'.I want to upload my application which be made Django to heroku.I run `heroku create xxxxxxxxx`. And I run `git push heroku` ,so

```
Counting objects: 6951, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5952/5952), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6951/6951), 11.21 MiB | 891.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6951 (delta 2087), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.5 (you are using python-3.6.4, which is unsupported).
remote:  !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.5).
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.4
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting alabaster==0.7.10 (from -r /tmp/build_6adefb27873345001cb4512d3fd963e3/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/c3/9b7dcd8548cf2c00531763ba154e524af575e8f36701bacfe5bcadc67440/alabaster-0.7.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting anaconda-client==1.6.9 (from -r /tmp/build_6adefb27873345001cb4512d3fd963e3/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.6.9 (from -r /tmp/build_6adefb27873345001cb4512d3fd963e3/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
remote:        No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.6.9 (from -r /tmp/build_6adefb27873345001cb4512d3fd963e3/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to xxxxxxxxx.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/xxxxxxxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xxxxxxxxx.git'
```

I searched this error,maybe `conda install pip` command should be installed.So I run it and heroku create command run again, but same error happens.What is wrong?How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that it cannot install anaconda-client, because it can't find version 1.6.9 which you specified in the requirements.txt. The latest version of that library on PyPi is [version 1.2.2](https://pypi.org/project/anaconda-client). However, it appears to be abandoned - why have you specified it at all? What are you using it for?

Comment: I delete anaconda-client from requirements.txt.And I run `git push heroku ` master command again, so how can I abandone it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Abandon what? Did you commit your changes?

Comment: I abandoned anaconda-client from requirements.txt. Yes,I commit my changes.